# How to retrieve a child class instance as sender in its base class event args?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class called `DataModel` that implements the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. In my app all my Models inherit from this app so that I don't have to code error handling logic nor change notification in any other classes. How can I raise the base class event below but send the child class that called it as a sender? I want to minimize repetitive code and would wish to avoid the whole virtual and override scenario.

```
virtual void SetErrors(string propertyName, List<string> propertyErrors)
{
    //clear any errors that already exist for this property
    errors.Remove(propertyName);

    //add the list of errors for the specified property
    errors.Add(propertyName, propertyErrors);

    //raise the error notification event
    if (ErrorsChanged != null)
        ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

### Edit- Question is not clear enough

For example say I have this class

```
public class GangMember : Models.Base_Classes.DataObject
{

    int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            if (value < 0)
            {
                List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                errors.Add("Age can not be less than 0.");
                SetErrors("Age", errors);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When `SetErrors()` is called in my base class `DataModel` it raises it's event `ErrorsChanged` and passes it an instance of itself `this`. How can I get a reference to the child class `GangMember` in this situation?

Comment: not sure what you're asking, if you need to pass the type of the child class just use `this.GetType()` because it comes off the instance it pulls the child class, not the parent.

Comment: Actually, the base class can also use `this.GetType()` and it will still get the child class type as a result. So you don't even need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Jon so in the scenario I put above, it will return my `GangMember` class? I thought the keyword `this` always returned a reference to the executing class in which case would be the base class?

Comment: Right, "this" returns the currently instantiated class. But the instantiated class and the class containing the code is not the same at runtime. So, using "this" will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` always points to the called class, not the implementing class.

```
public class A
{
    public void PrintType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().ToString());
    }
}

public class B : A
{
}

// ...

new B().PrintType(); // This will give "B", not "A".
```